# Grant permissions on GPO creation in Organizational Unit

Tags: windows, gpo

Could anyone tell me please how can I grant permissions on creating Group Policy Objects to user or group (NON-domain-admin, just domain-user). User should be able to create GPO only in specific OU and children OUs but wan't be able to create or edit GROs in others. How to do it?

P.S. Domain is based on Windows Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

GPOs are not created in OUs, but they are linked to them. So you need to adjust ACLs in two places:

The user in question must have the access right to create GPOs in your domain. And he must have the access right to link GPOs to the OU in question.